# How to create a PayPal subscription order?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using [PayPal Checkout API SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK) and I successfully created an order using the smart buttons, so when the user click on the paypal button an order is created.  Here's my code for the final capture:

```
let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
    request.requestBody({
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": 'EUR',
                "value": '15.00', 
            },
            "redirect_urls": {
                "return_url": `${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/pay/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
                "cancel_url": `${process.env.APP_DOMAIN}/pay/cancel?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
            }
        }]
    });
```

What I don't understand is: how can I actually create a subscription order? I need to make a monthly subscription, but I can't find anything in the documentation that allows me to create such a checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Subscriptions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) is newer and most SDKs don't support it yet (and if they do support billing plan calls, it's for an older, incompatible version, generally)

So you probably need to implement direct HTTPS API calls (no SDK) to create the necessary Product and Plan. All those curl calls you see in the documentation? Do the equivalent from node.

Then in the last step you pass the resulting plan object to the client-side SPB js.

Comment: Thanks @Preston for your answer, I was having suspicions indeed... If I can make a small note, I find the PayPal API unnecessarily complicated, they should review everything a little to reach the quality level of Stripe